why libaio renaming to libaio1t in ubuntu24
I found the question here: libaio1 on Noble?, but I want to know why Ubuntu 24.04 renamed this library.
I can't find any related information in the release notes except for this:
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS solves the Year 2038 problem 319 that existed on armhf. 
More than a thousand packages have been updated to handle time using a 64-bit value rather than a 32-bit one, making it possible to handle times up to 292 billion years in the future. 

I want to know if this library was only renamed, or if there were some significant modifications made to it.
